# JSON data isn't appending to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, append

I can see the JSON when I run `console.log`, and I think the problem has something to do with my `return` statement.

#### JS:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import headlineData from '../JSON/headline.json';

export default class {
    constructor() {
        this.loadHeadlineData();
    }

   // ------------------- //

    loadHeadlineData() {
        let res = headlineData.d.results.map(function(obj) {
            return {
                "Name": obj.preferredname,
                "Initials": obj.initials,
                "Title": obj.jobtitle,
                "Office": obj.office
            }
        })       
        $("#headline-cont h1").append(res);   
    }

}

console.log(headlineData)
```

#### JSON:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [{
            "preferredname": "Bobson A. Dugnutt",
            "initials": "BAD",
            "jobtitle": "Coolguy",
            "office": "New York"
        }]
    }
}
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
<div id="headline-cont">
   <h1></h1>
</div>
```

#### `console.log(JSON.stringify(headlineData.d.results))`:

```
[{"preferredname":"Bobson A. Dugnutt","initials":"BAD","jobtitle":"Coolguy","office":"New York"}]
```

Comment: try using `JSON.stringify(res)`

Comment: @MaheerAli Nothing, unfortunately :\

Comment: @Jeto good to know, thanks. I updated my code (still nothing's rendering)

Comment: @Jeto I added the HTML and console results into the question body.

Comment: Could you show the result of `console.log($("#headline-cont h1"));`? Also, maybe try `window.$ = $` after the import, not sure this is needed as I never use jQuery in that kind of context.

Comment: @Jeto: `jQuery.fn.init(2) [div#headline-cont, h1, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]`

Comment: Are you sure you tried `$("#headline-cont h1").append(JSON.stringify(res))` as the first comment suggested? There seems to be no other reason this wouldn't work, and appending a JS object would most likely do nothing.

Comment: Absolutely positive. It's currently what I have now (also tried `headline-cont,h1`) and nothing's changed. Under the dev tool's Elements I can see that nothing's been added--I'd wondered if maybe they were there but off screen. Yeah this problem has been bugging me because I feel that it should be working.

Comment: Your `console.log($("#headline-cont h1"));` result suggests that there are two matching elements. Are you sure you have only one element with an ID of `headline-cont`? Does it contain two `<h1>`? Are both of them empty?

Comment: `headline-cont` contains just one `h1` and it's empty...hm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188365/discussion-between-jeto-and-bodrov).

Answer (score 1):

Use `,` to separate the two classes used in the selector

```
$(".headline-cont,h1")
```

```js
var headlineData={
    "d": {
        "results": [{
            "preferredname": "Bobson A. Dugnutt",
            "initials": "BAD",
            "jobtitle": "Coolguy",
            "office": "New York"
        }]
    }
};
    function loadHeadlineData() {
        let res = headlineData.d.results.filter(function(obj) {
            return {
                "Name": obj.preferredname,
                "Initials": obj.initials,
                "Title": obj.jobtitle,
                "Office": obj.office
            }
        })     
       // console.log(res)
        $(".headline-cont,h1").append(JSON.stringify(res));   
    }


loadHeadlineData();
//console.log(headlineData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headline-cont h1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Several points:

1. (Before OP edited) Inside `filter`, it should be an expression that returns `true` / `false`.  `filter` takes in an array, returning an array which evaluates to `true`.  E.g. `[1,2,3].filter( n => n % 2 === 1 );` gives `[1,3]`. *Do you want to use `map` instead?*
2. When we use `append`, we should be appending jQuery DOM objects, e.g. `$(...).append($("<h1>"+res+"</h1>"));`;  *Do you want to use `text()` instead? (If the `<h1>` is already there)*  If not there, you may instead delete `h1` from the selector and use `append`.
3. Currently `res` is an array (no matter `map` or `filter` is used).  You may want to use `res[0].Name` finally.  However if you do really want to output the whole array / json, use `JSON.stringify`.